# DiffUtil Not working in nested recyclerview Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-diffutils

I have two recycler views. My view is not updated until I used `notifyDataSetChanged`. I asked for a similar type of [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69715381/11560810), but this time I have [Github](https://github.com/vivek-modi/DiffUtilExample) Link. So please have a look and explain to me what I am doing wrong. Thanks

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.diffutilexample

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.diffutilexample.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<ActivityViewModel>()
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var groupAdapter: GroupAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupViewModel()
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        viewModel.fetchData()

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.addData()
        }
    }

    private fun setupViewModel() {
        viewModel.groupListLiveData.observe(this) {
            if (groupAdapter == null) {
                groupAdapter = GroupAdapter()
                binding.recyclerview.adapter = groupAdapter
            }
            groupAdapter?.submitList(viewModel.groupList?.toMutableList())
            binding.recyclerview.post {
                groupAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ActivityViewModel.kt**

```
package com.example.diffutilexample

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class ActivityViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    var groupListLiveData: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()
    var groupList: ArrayDeque<Group>? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            groupListLiveData.postValue(true)
        }
    var value = 0

    fun fetchData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = ApiInterface.create().getResponse()

            groupList = groupByData(response.abc)
        }
    }

    private fun groupByData(abc: List<Abc>?): ArrayDeque<Group> {
        val result: ArrayDeque<Group> = groupList ?: ArrayDeque()

        abc?.iterator()?.forEach { item ->
            val key = GroupKey(item.qwe)
            result.addFirst(Group(key, mutableListOf(item)))
        }
        return result
    }

    fun addData() {
        groupList?.let { lastList ->
            val qwe = Qwe("Vivek ${value++}", "Modi")
            val item = Abc(type = "Type 1", "Adding Message", qwe)
            val lastGroup = lastList[0]
            lastGroup.list.add(item)
            groupList = lastList
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the whole code in Github Link. I attached in above

Comment: Log the `groupList` above this line `groupAdapter?.submitList(viewModel.groupList?.toMutableList())`. Check if correct data is logged every time it changes.

Comment: @ArpitShukla I logged it my data is adding in list and if I used **notifyDataSetChanged** is working fine

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged can't change the log output. Are you getting correct log output (with or without) notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: @ArpitShukla yes log is giving me correct output when I add data. with or without) **notifyDataSetChanged**

Comment: Instead of giving an answer, I would question why you think DiffUtil was not being triggered? I bet one way to debug your codes, would be to add logging points in `areItemsTheSame()` and  `areContentsTheSame()` to see if DiffUitil is actually trying to do comparison. If you have implemented the functions incorrectly, in the way that DiffUtil thinks nothing has changed, then obviously the RecyclerView will not show the updated values as you expected.

Comment: @RyanWong what can I log can you give me example?

Comment: @RyanWong nothing triggered in my second adapter diffutil comparator, I tried to add log in there

Comment: @RyanWong Only First One is triggering and printing the log

Comment: @vivek-modi if it has been triggered, you may insert log to check what the return values for both functions are - to make sure they return `false` if you expect things are different, otherwise your recyclerView items won't get refreshed.  if it has not been triggered, then it give you the clue to check why `.submitList()` has not been called. You could trace the source of error step by step

Comment: @RyanWong Sorry I tried to lot to understand, but I was unable to get it.  But still trying :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't debugged this, but if you remove your overuse of MutableLists and `var`s, and simplify your LiveData, you will likely eliminate your bug. At the very least, it will help you track down the problem.

MutableLists and DiffUtil do not play well together!

For example, Group's list should be a read-only List:

```
data class Group(
    val key: GroupKey,
    val list: List<Abc?> = emptyList()
)
```

It's convoluted to have a LiveData that only reports if some other property is usable. Then you're dealing with nullability all over the place here and in the observer, so it becomes hard to tell when some code is going to be skipped or not from a null-safe call. I would change your LiveData to directly publish a read-only List. You can avoid nullable Lists by using `emptyList()` to also simplify code.

You can avoid publicly showing your interior workings with the ArrayDeque as well. And you are lazy loading the ArrayDeque unnecessarily, which leads to having to deal with nullability unnecessarily.

```
class ActivityViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val _groupList = MutableLiveData<List<Group>>()
    val groupList: LiveData<List<Group>> get() = _groupList
    private val trackedGroups = ArrayDeque<Group>()
    private var counter = 0

    fun fetchData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = ApiInterface.create().getResponse()
            addFetchedData(response.abc.orEmpty())
            _groupList.value = trackedGroups.toList() // new copy for observers
        }
    }

    private fun addFetchedData(abcList: List<Abc>) {
        for (item in abcList) {
            val key = GroupKey(item.qwe)
            trackedGroups.addFirst(Group(key, listOf(item)))
        }
    }

    fun addData() {
        if (trackedGroups.isEmpty())
            return // Might want to create a default instead of doing nothing?
        val qwe = Qwe("Vivek ${counter++}", "Modi")
        val item = Abc(type = "Type 1", "Adding Message", qwe)
        val group = trackedGroups[0]
        trackedGroups[0] = group.copy(list = group.list + item)

        _groupList.value = trackedGroups.toList() // new copy for observers
    }
}
```

In your Activity, since your GroupAdapter has no dependencies, you can instantiate it at the call site to avoid dealing with lazy loading it. And you can set it to the RecyclerView in `onCreate()` immediately.

Because of the changes in ViewModel, observing becomes very simple.

If you do something in `setupViewModel()` that updates a view immediately, you'll have a crash, so you should move it after calling `setContentView()`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<ActivityViewModel>()
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val groupAdapter = GroupAdapter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply {
            setContentView(root)
            recyclerview.adapter = groupAdapter
            button.setOnClickListener {
                viewModel.addData()
            }
        }

        setupViewModel()
        viewModel.fetchData()
    }

    private fun setupViewModel() {
        viewModel.groupList.observe(this) {
            groupAdapter.submitList(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Your `DiffUtil.ItemCallback.areItemsTheSame` in GroupAdapter is incorrect. You are only supposed to check if they represent the same item, not if their contents are the same, so it should not be comparing lists.

```
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Group, newItem: Group): Boolean {
    return oldItem.key == newItem.key
}
```

And in GroupViewHolder, you are creating a new adapter for the inner RecyclerView every time it is rebound. That defeats the purpose of using RecyclerView at all. You should only create the adapter once.

I am predicting that the change in the nested list is going to look weird when the view is being recycled rather than just updated, because it will animate the change from what was in the view previously, which could be from a different item. So we should probably track the old item key and avoid the animation if the new key doesn't match. I think this can be done in the `submitList()` callback parameter to run after the list contents have been updated in the adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but I haven't tested it.

```
class GroupViewHolder(val binding: ItemLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    
    companion object {
        //...
    }

    private val adapter = NestedGroupAdapter().also {
        binding.nestedRecyclerview.adapter = it
    }

    private var previousKey: GroupKey? = null

    fun bindItem(item: Group?) {
        val skipAnimation = item?.key != previousKey
        previousKey = item?.key
        adapter.submitList(item?.list.orEmpty()) {
            if (skipAnimation) adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: your adapters' `bindView` functions are confusingly named. I would just make those into secondary constructors and you can make the primary constructor private.

```
class GroupViewHolder private constructor(private val binding: ItemLayoutBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    constructor(parent: ViewGroup) : this(
        ItemLayoutBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 great answer..

Comment: what is **item?.list.orEmpty()** in bindItem function ?

Comment: Safe call on `item` since it’s nullable. `orEmpty()` turns a nullable list reference to a non-null list reference by replacing null with an empty list if it’s null. This way, we ensure we are clearing old data in the recycled view if we get a blank row item.

Comment: Hey can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70593277/11560810)

Comment: I’ve never used ViewPager.

Comment: do you know someone who can help me on this.

Comment: can you see this new [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70681724/11560810)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, and I admit I haven't extensively studied your code, and this is not a solution, but this might point you in the right direction of how to solve it.

The thing about

```
groupAdapter?.submitList(viewModel.groupList?.toMutableList())
```

Is that `toMutableList()` does indeed make a copy of the list. But each of the objects in the list are not copies. If you add things to an object in the original list, like you do in `addData()` it in fact is also already added to the copy that is in the adapter. That's why a new submitList doesn't recognize it as a change because it is actually the same as it was before the submitList.

As far as I understand, working with DiffUtil works best if the list you submit only contains objects that are immutable, so mistakes like this can't happen. I have ran into a similar problem before and the solution is also not straightforward. In fact, I don't entirely remember how I solved it back then, but hopefully this pushes you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried every [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49726385/11560810)  but it's not working.

Comment: That's why I add my sample project.

Comment: Hey @IvoBeckers can you see this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70681724/11560810)

Comment: @vivekmodi this website is not meant to just poke people to look at your questions. You should not ask specific people. And this is not a messaging website.

Comment: Sorry  I'll never do it again.